# Applying an opacity filter over an image on html

Tags: html, css, image, filter, opacity

I was trying to find this solution but I can only find solutions to apply filter on images as background-image on css.

I have a row with 3 images in equal size on my HTML. 
The effect that I am trying to replicate is a "filter" on all of the photos that give a gradient opacity. This filter has a bottom completely dark and starts getting transparent until reaching the top. (a little bit like this: http://www.webdesignerwall.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/css-gradient-box.gif where the white top would be transparent)

How could I do that, considering that images are 100% responsive and changes for every time we change the size of the browser.

PS: The gradient code is not a problem, I can do that, the problem I can't find the solution is how to apply a "DIV" or something over each of those images that always follow the image size, no matter its height and width.

Here's my HTML:

```
<section class="home-page-gallery">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">

          <!-- FIRST IMAGE -->
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 no-padding yellow-bg">
                <div class="gallery-item">
                  <img src="images/photo01.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>

          <!-- SECOND IMAGE -->
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 no-padding blue-bg">
              <div class="gallery-item">
                  <img src="images/photo02.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>

          <!-- THIRD IMAGE -->
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 no-padding pink-bg">
              <div class="gallery-item">
                  <img src="images/photo03.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>

          </div><!-- ./ row -->
        </div><!-- ./ container-fluid -->
      </section>
```

and the CSS:

```
.gallery-item{
  width:100%;
}

.gallery-item img{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

I already tried to put another div wrapping each image, giving a position: relative and a z-index trying to make this div stay over the image, but it didn't work

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pseudo-element like this:

```css
.gallery-item {
  width: 100%;
  position:relative;
}
.gallery-item:after {
 content:"";
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 bottom:0;
 background:linear-gradient(to top,red 20%,transparent 80%);
}
.gallery-item img {
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section class="home-page-gallery">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

      <!-- FIRST IMAGE -->
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 no-padding yellow-bg">
        <div class="gallery-item">
          <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- SECOND IMAGE -->
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 no-padding blue-bg">
        <div class="gallery-item">
          <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- THIRD IMAGE -->
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 no-padding pink-bg">
        <div class="gallery-item">
          <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- ./ row -->
  </div>
  <!-- ./ container-fluid -->
</section>
```

Comment: wow, your suggestion works perfectly, thank you so much my friend. Do you know what property may I use to make the separation between the dark and transparent to be more close to the bottom?

Comment: @jorge simply adjust the % value of colors ;) i edited my answer so you can see where the values should go

Comment: @Jorge i also suggest to read more about here : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient as you can use rgba color, add many  colors, etc

Answer (score 1):

you need a element that is a sibling to the image, inside the `gallery-item` wrapper.

you want to do something like this with your css:

```
.gallery-item{
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
}

.gallery-item img{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
}
```

position the outer container as `relative`, then position the gradient el as absolute. here is a fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/y9o1paex/11/